# How to load and unload Image Objects quickly for an animated PNG sequence ? (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, animation, buffer

I have this little issue with my game in Java, basically I have to do an animated sequence of images in the background of the game's menu. I approach the problem in a pretty simple way (no need to make it complex), so I just have a JPanel in a Jframe and the whole thing is processed in the EDT. The animation part works great, I used timers to animate the sequence and I reach 60fps whithout any issue. The problem is that the pictures are heavy, like full HD in PNG for all of them. So the first issue that I had was when i loaded the entire 900 frames sequence at once in the memory, the JVM just sayed nop not enough memory and yeah it takes something like 8Gb when everything is loaded (due to the rasterzation in memory of the pictures). So I can't have all of them at once in the memory and I need to fetch them dynamically.

I tried to create some kind of FrameBuffer in which I want to put like 10 pictures at most when the game is running, and I want the animation to ask the current frame to the buffer, and when the buffer thinks that it's time to refetch some Images it does it. The thing is that it's not smooth at all..

This is what the buffer looks like :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class FrameBuffer
{
    private int bufferSize; // the desired buffer size
    private int numberOfFrames; // the total number of frames of the sequence
    private int currentFrameIndex;
    private int endBufferFrameIndex;
    private ArrayList<Image> frames;
    private String frameFolderURL;
    private boolean isFilling;
    private FillBufferJob fillBufferJob;

    private class FillBufferJob extends SwingWorker<Void,Void>
    {
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
        {
            isFilling = true;

            for(int i = 0 ; i < bufferSize/2 && endBufferFrameIndex < numberOfFrames ; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    frames.add(ImageIO.read(new File(getCurrentFrameUrl(endBufferFrameIndex))));
                    endBufferFrameIndex++;
                }
                catch(IOException e){}
            }

            isFilling = false;

            return null;
        }

        protected void done()
        {
            
        }
    }

    public FrameBuffer(int bufferSize, int numberOfFrames, String frameFolderURL)
    {
        this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
        this.numberOfFrames = numberOfFrames;
        this.frameFolderURL = frameFolderURL;
        
        initFrames();
    }

    public void initFrames()
    {
        isFilling = false;
        currentFrameIndex = 0;
        endBufferFrameIndex = 0;
        frames = new ArrayList<Image>();

        if(bufferSize > numberOfFrames) bufferSize = numberOfFrames;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < bufferSize ; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                frames.add(ImageIO.read(new File(getCurrentFrameUrl(i))));
                endBufferFrameIndex++;
            }
            catch(IOException e){}
        }
    }

    public int getCurrentFrameIndex()
    {
        return currentFrameIndex;
    }

    public Image getCurrentFrame()
    {
        if(frames.size() < bufferSize/2 && !isFilling)
        {
            fillBufferJob = new FillBufferJob();
            fillBufferJob.execute();
        }

        if(frames.size() == 1 && fillBufferJob != null)
        {
            try
            {
                fillBufferJob.get();
                fillBufferJob = null;
            }
            catch(InterruptedException|java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException e){}
        }
        
        currentFrameIndex++;
        return frames.remove(0);
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        initFrames();
    }

    public String getCurrentFrameUrl(int index)
    {
        if((index+1) < 10) return frameFolderURL+"/000"+(index+1)+".jpg";
        else if((index+1) < 100) return frameFolderURL+"/00"+(index+1)+".jpg";
        else if((index+1) < 1000) return frameFolderURL+"/0"+(index+1)+".jpg";
        else return "";
    }
}
```

So for now the code is not that clean but what I'd like is just some advice about the method getCurrentFrame(), this is where the logic is happening, when you ask for a frame it checks if the actual number of pictures in the buffer (the array list) is inferior to half of the initial buffer size mentioned in the constructor, and if so a SwingWorker is invoked to fetch the missing pictures of the buffer, in this case 5 pictures. It's working properly but it's not smooth at all, obviously because it's rendered at 60fps and this gets called a lot and ImageIO fetching is not that fast.

So yeah I don't really need help for debugging the whole thing because it works, just some advice for the buffer on how could I do it better ?

Thank you !

Comment: You can have more images in the buffer, you can slow down the animation to 30 frames per second and/or you can reduce the quality of the images.  There is no magic bullet.  Disk input will be thousands of times slower than CPU or GPU rendering.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc *"There is no magic bullet."* Too true! I was about to suggest encoding the images into a video, but you'd need Java-FX (or Swing, JMF and a primitive format like .MOV) to bring that onscreen.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: True, you could use an encoder/decoder to reduce the size of the images as a group.  A Github search came up with [this project](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/).

Comment: Thank you very much four your answers, @GilbertLeBlanc I've been thinking about it yesterday and yeah my conclusion was also that it was always going to be slow to load the images from the disk..

Comment: So i'm thinking maybe I should try to load a video instead as @Andrew Thompson mentioned and i'm gonna look up the JMF ! Thanks again guys :)